# Max number from database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have some trouble with finding the max number in a database.
Have a question here also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/295657/max-number-from-sql.html
A Table with the name Person and the column Score
I want to find the highest score in Score

```
public class Person
 {
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int PersonID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }      
     public string RollNo { get; set; }
     public string G1 { get; set; }
     public string G2 { get; set; }
     public string G3 { get; set; }
     public string G4 { get; set; }
     public string G5 { get; set; }
     public string G6 { get; set; }
     public string G7 { get; set; }
     public string G8 { get; set; }
     public string G9 { get; set; }
     public string G10 { get; set; }
     public string G11 { get; set; }
     public string G12 { get; set; }
     public string G13 { get; set; }
     public string G14 { get; set; }
     public string G15 { get; set; }
     public string G16 { get; set; }
     public string G17 { get; set; }
     public string G18 { get; set; }
     public string Score { get; set; }
 }
```

And This

```
  public Task<List<Person>> GetItemsHighscore()
    {

      return db.QueryAsync < Person >("select * from [Person] where [Score]=(select max([Score]) from [Person])");  
        
    }
```

And showing in a CollectionView

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstPersons3.ItemsSource = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsHighscore();

    }
```

But it is showing the highest number based on the first number , for example 4 is higher then 11

I think maybe the problem is String ?

Also tryed this but that is not helping.
There were no errors but the outcome is the same

What do i have to do or change ?

```
public decimal Score { get; set; }  // in Class


Score = (decimal)double.Parse(resultText.Text), // Save



resultText.Text = person.Score.ToString(); // Show
```

In the image in HIGH there must be 11 and not 4

[image]

Comment: you should never store numeric values as strings in your db - that is your fundamental problem

Comment: Now i know that after 2 days of trouble , how do i change the database to store numeric values

Comment: SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
        public SQLiteHelper(string dbPath)
        {
            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTableAsync<Person>().Wait();       
            db.CreateTableAsync<Spellen>().Wait();
                      
        }

Comment: change your table definition to use decimal instead of string

Comment: This is what i tryed already but the outcome is the same 

// change it to decimal
   public decimal Score { get; set; }
     
 // Save it
  Score = (decimal)double.Parse(resultText.Text),

 // Load 
   resultText.Text = person.Score.ToString();

 // Show in CollectionView
   Label Text="{Binding Score}"

Comment: Having second thoughts about this for saving
Score = (decimal)double.Parse(resultText.Text),

Comment: first, please do not stuff code in comments, it is very difficult to read.  2nd, why not use `Decimal.Parse`?

Comment: @Jason Never used Decimal.Parse can you tell me what to change to save resultText.Text ?

Comment: replace `Double.Parse()` with `Decimal.Parse()` and remove the unneeded cast

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a select with descending  order (with cast to integer) and get only first result :

```
select * from person ORDER BY CAST(score AS INTEGER) Desc limit 1;
```

Comment: i give it a try Ptit Xav  , what does this do `Score < 2 ORDER BY CAST`

Comment: Edited my previous comment : use limit to get only one row

Comment: Thanks Ptit Xav , that seams to work . But i think it is better to change the Column to Decimal for futher calculations .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jason

Using this and it works

public decimal Score { get; set; }  // in Class

Score = Decimal.Parse(resultText.Text), // Save